# Jedis connection is not closed by the jedis.close() method

Tags: jedis

I am using Redis for storing  my data. When I issue `jedis.close()` from my server, the connection is not closed, it is still showing in the list of connections (e.g. the `CLIENT LIST` command in Redis still shows the Jedis connection). If the server is shutdown, the connection ends in Redis.

Why doesn't the `jedis.close()` method close the connection? Can someone explain this behaviour?

I attached the code snippet:

```
try
{
    GenericObjectPoolConfig  poolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
    poolConfig.setMaxTotal(MAX_ACTIVE_POOL);
    poolConfig.setMaxIdle(MAX_IDLE);
    poolConfig.setMinIdle(MIN_IDLE);
    pool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, SINGLE_REDIS_IP, SINGLE_REDIS_IP_PORT, TIMEOUT, REDIS_PASSWORD,REDIS_RDB_NUMBER);
    Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
    jedis.clientSetname("TestRedis");
    System.out.println(jedis.smembers("apikey"));
    System.out.println(jedis.get("apikey"));
    if(jedis != null && jedis.isConnected())
        jedis.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You are using a pool. When you close a connection when using pooling, then the connection must return to the pool and not close. This list of connections that you are seeing, does it contain the pool's connections too?